# Java concurrency with arraylists (How to handle this?)

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern, concurrentmodification

It is true that you get a ConcurrentModificationException error when you try and modify an arraylist when iterating through it, yes? But how does the error still persist if you first **remove** the element you want to modify, iterate through the list, and then **insert** the element back? I do not understand if the logic is like this why it throws a concurrentmodificationexception.

This whole program uses the Observer Pattern.

---

The purpose of the program is to have multiple text boxes, when you type in one, the others update with the same text.

**Subject** - Interface

```
public interface Subject {

public void attach(Observer o);
public void detach(Observer o);
public void notifyAllObservers();
}
```

**SubjectImpl** - implements Subject

```
import java.util.*;

public class SubjectImpl implements Subject {

private List <Observer> observers;

public SubjectImpl(){
    observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
}


@Override
public void attach(Observer o) {
    observers.add(o);
}

@Override
public void detach(Observer o) {
    observers.remove(o);
}

@Override
public void notifyAllObservers() {
            //Iterating code
    for(Observer o: observers){
        o.update();
    }
}
}
```

**Observer** - interface

```
public interface Observer {
public void update();
}
```

**Editor** - Implements Observer

```
import java.awt.*
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class Editor extends JFrame implements DocumentListener, Observer {

private FileContentSubject reference;

    private JScrollPane textAreaScrollPane;
    private JTextArea textArea;


public Editor(FileContentSubject filecontentsubject) throws IOException {
    super("Editor");
    initComponents();

    this.reference = filecontentsubject;
    textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(reference);
    textArea.getDocument().putProperty("ownerEditor", this); 
}


private void initComponents(){

    textArea = new JTextArea();       

    //set location, size, visible and defaultcloseoperation here        

    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getContentPane().add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}



@Override
public void update() {
    textArea.setText(reference.getState()); //Call to update each text box
}


@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
}


@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
}


@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
}
}
```

**File Content System** - Acts as concrete subject in Observer (there only exists one)

```
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class FileContentSubject implements Subject, DocumentListener {

private String state; //Current, most recent copy of everything

public String getState() {
    return this.state;
}

private SubjectImpl reference;

@Override
public void attach(Observer o) {
    reference.attach(o);
}

@Override
public void detach(Observer o) {
    reference.detach(o);
}

@Override
public void notifyAllObservers() {
    reference.notifyAllObservers();
}

public FileContentSubject() {
    reference = new SubjectImpl();
}

@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
}

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {

    Document doc = (Document) arg0.getDocument();
    try {
        this.state = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Editor e = (Editor) doc.getProperty("ownerEditor");
    reference.detach(e); 
    notifyAllObservers(); 
    reference.attach(e); 
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {

   //same as insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) ^^
}

}
```

Comment: I am also baffled by the lack of any iterating code... Post the code relevant to the exception...

Comment: Indeed for better help sooner, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your `ConcurrentModificationException` is only thrown when 3 or more editors are used, right? Anyway, let me try to explain what is happening.

Let's suppose you have 3 `Editor` instances: "Editor1", "Editor2" and "Editor3".

This is what happens when you type a text into "Editor1" (or, how I call it, when you "begin the chain of events"):

```
User types on Editor1 // chain begins
FileContentSubject detaches editor: Editor1
FileContentSubject begin notifyAllObservers(): [Editor2, Editor3]
    Editor2 receives update() to new state
```

So far, normal behavior, right? The thing is when Editor2's `update()` is called, it changes Editor2's `textArea`, and `FileContentSubject` **is** a `DocumentListener` of that `textArea` as well (as it was of Editor1's `textArea`).

This triggers a new edition, thus creating a **new** "chain of events". In practice, here's what will happen (repeating from the beginning):

```
User types on Editor1 // chain begins
FileContentSubject detaches editor: Editor1
FileContentSubject begin notifyAllObservers(): [Editor2, Editor3] // first notification
    Editor2 receives update() to new state // another chain begins! (the 1st chain didn't end yet!)
        FileContentSubject detaches editor: Editor2
        FileContentSubject begin notifyAllObservers(): [Editor3]
            Editor3 receives update() to new state // chain THREE!!
                FileContentSubject detaches editor: Editor3
                FileContentSubject begin notifyAllObservers(): [] // empty list... nobody to notify
                FileContentSubject reattaches editor: Editor3
                FileContentSubject ended notifyAllObservers(): [Editor3] // chain 3 over
        FileContentSubject reattaches editor: Editor2
        FileContentSubject ended notifyAllObservers(): [Editor3, Editor2] // chain 2 over
```

This is the point where `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown. But where exactly is it throw, on the code?

Actually, it's on `SubjectImpl`(!):

```
@Override
public void notifyAllObservers() {
    for (Observer o : observers) {
        o.update();
    }
}
```

**What is the problem?**

The thing is:

- Notice that in the line with the `// first notification` comment there's a call to `notifyAllObservers()`
- At his moment the list of attached observers is (in this order) [Editor2, Editor3].
- `notifyAllObservers()`, when called, then, begins iterating on that list

  - the first step of the iteration is to call `Editor2.update()`.

    - `Editor2.update()` starts a whole new chain...
    - and when that chain ends, the list of attached observers is now [Editor3, Editor2] 
      (notice: the order has changed!)
  - when `notifyAllObservers()` tries to continue its iteration to the next step, it notices that the list has changed and... bam! `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.

Why? Because you cannot change a list where you have begun to iterate. (Either using an iterator, or "foreach".)

### The solution:

There may be many, but the simplest is just to stop the "chain of events". To do that, just change `update()` on `Editor` from:

```
@Override
public void update() {
    textArea.setText(reference.getState()); // Call to update each text box
}
```

To:

```
@Override
public void update() {
    textArea.getDocument().removeDocumentListener(reference);
    textArea.setText(reference.getState()); // Call to update each text box
    textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(reference);
}
```

What does it mean? It means that when an `Editor` changes itself **due to anybody else** and not some typing on its `textArea`, he won't notify `FileContentSubject` (the `DocumentListener`) anymore, he'll just change, quietly.

This will stop any second chain of events from beginning in the first place.

Hope I managed to explain the problem! If I can make any point clearer, just let me know! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much again acdcjunior, your very thorough in explaining the question, you helped me exceptionally well learn this concept through and through!

Comment: What a fantastic and insightful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no questions about the code, I'm answering on sentences with question marks.

> It is true that you get a ConcurrentModificationException error when
>   you try and modify an arraylist when iterating through it, yes?

True.
To raise ConcurrentModificationException you need to modify a list calling methods on the list and then trying to continue iterating.

> But how does the error still persist if you first remove the element
>   you want to modify, iterate through the list, and then insert the
>   element back? I do not understand if the logic is like this why it
>   throws a concurrentmodificationexception.

When you create iterator with List.iterator() you create a contract with List that you will do all modifications to the List with the iterator object you just created.

If you remove an element directly - List.remove() - you break the contract.

If you add an element directly - List.add() - you break the contract.

List or list iterator do not care if you modify the element itself.

Hope, that will clarify things for you.